# what is the convention for calling overloaded = operator in C++ using pointers?

Tags: c++

When overloading a "=" operator for a class, the usual syntax is:

```
ClassA ObjA, ObjB;

ObjA = ObjB;
```

But what about pointers ??

```
Class *PtrA, *PtrB;

PtrA->operator=(PtrB)
```

Is the above calling convention correct assuming the `=` operator in ClassA is defined for pointer on class (`ClassA* operator=(const ClassA* obj)`) ??

Answer (score 3):

Usually the assignment operator will be defined only for the class, and not the pointers, and then you can do:

```
*ptrA = *ptrB;
```

Comment: However, Is PtrA->operator=(PtrB) calling convention correct ??

Comment: Assignment operators rarely are written to take pointers, usually they take const references.  So I'd say this is the best answer, and your example `PtrA->operator=(PtrB)` should be avoided.

Comment: `*ptrA = *ptrB` is equivalent to `ptrA->operator=(*ptrB)`, but definitely preferred

Comment: To directly answer @de costo, your form of the statement is incorrect (from a convention standpoint).  If for some reason you really don't want to use the typical `*ptrA = *ptrB`, use `ptrA->operator=(*ptrB)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not that in your example

```
Class *PtrA, *PtrB;

PtrA->operator=(PtrB)
```

You are not passing in an instance of PtrB, you are passing in a pointer to a PtrB;

Actually of course your code doesnt really make sense. You cannot say

```
Class *PtrA, *PtrB;
```

I think you mean

```
Class A
{
}
Class B
{
  B operator=(const A &rhs){...}
}

A *ptra = ...
B *ptrb = ...
```

In this case you can go

```
*ptrb = *ptra;
```

or

```
ptrb->operator=(*ptra);
```

you certainly cannot go

```
ptrb->operator=(ptra)
```

or (the equivalent simple syntax)

```
*ptrbb = ptra
```

Answer (score 1):

If the assignement operator in `ClassA` accepts an argument of type `ClassA *` (or `const ClassA *`), then you can call it as either

```
 PtrA->operator =(PtrB);
```

or as

```
*PtrA = PtrB;
```

The latter is more natural way to use the assigment operator for obvious reasons.

However, defining the assignment operator to accept an argument of type `ClassA *` is a rather bizzare thing to do. Normally, assignment operator of `ClassA` would accept an argument of type `const ClassA &` and be invoked as

```
*PtrA = *PtrB;
```